# Anything wrong with leaving timer on and using a flag to control execution on/off?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer, polling

I'm polling a router from an iPhone.  The timer only fires every 60 seconds.  I'm starting the timer in ViewDidLoad and leaving it on.

There's a flag pollingON initially set FALSE.

When the timer fires, it calls myTimerFiredMethod, which then checks,

```
if (self.pollingON) {
  self.pollingON = FALSE ;
  // run the polling code
  self.pollingON = TRUE ;
}
```

Aside from wasting a nanosecond or two of CPU time, anything wrong with this practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer that is running although not in use, is a waste of battery life. It's also a strange design pattern, running a timer without a cause.

Also if you turn on Polling, at worst you will have to wait almost 60 seconds before an update.

I would not recommend implementing it that way. Instead, invalidate the timer when polling is turned off and create a new timer when polling is turned on.

Comment: When polling is turned on by a button click, I also immediately call the polling routine.  How much battery life do you think gets used by a timer that fires once a minute?  Also, the only purpose of this app is polling the router.

Comment: Man Of One Way is right. It isn't so much a matter of resources (in this particular case) but why not go with the more correct design pattern to begin with? Especially when it would only take an extra 5 minutes (if that) to implement?

Comment: Great name for a design antipattern - Timer Without A Cause

Comment: @cyberBeach I don't think that the purpose of the app matters here. It's still a bad design. :)

Comment: So as I understand the comments, the responses are expressing a design preference for invalidating the timer when polling is turned off by the user and then instantiating a new timer when the polling is turned on.  Of course, when a timer fires the very first line of the called method should turn off the timer on the first line to avoid (technical term:) "pile-ups" on the timer thread.